# How can I use createPortal without extra div in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Often I use createPortal like the code below:

```js
        const containerEle = document.createElement('div');
        const App = function(){
            useEffect(()=>{
            document.body.appendChild(containerEle);
            return ()=>{
              document.body.removeChild(containerEle);
            }
          },[])
            return createPortal(<div className="my-component"/>, containerEle);
        }
```

which will render like

```html
<div><div className="my-component"/></div>
```

but actually I just wanna

```html
<div className="my-component"/>
```

I try to modify createElement('div') to fragment like

```js
 const containerEle = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

It works, but in typescript, it tells me the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'DocumentFragment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
```

For `createDocumentFragment` returns DocumentFragment.
How should I modify my code to get this error off?

Comment: you can attach the class name to the container div `containerEle.className= 'my-component'` if this is the behavior you are looking for

Comment: @LHIOUI Thanks for reply, but it's not an ideal solution. `<div className="my-component"/>` here only want to tell it's a component, it may be much more complex than just a div.